# Load excel file into PHP_Excel from variable

Tags: php, phpexcel

I currently have this

```
file_put_contents($tmpfile, $attachments[0]['body']);
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($tmpfile);
```

The file I am reading is extracted from an email, so rather then writing it to a tempfile
I would like to read it directly into phpexcel from a string (if that makes sense)

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($attachments[0]['body']);
```

I have looked at the php excel manual but can't see how to do it, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHPExcel provides no direct method for loading from a string rather than from a file. As an alternative to actually creating a physical filesystem file for $tmpfile though, you might be able to use [`php://memory`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#~//memory) or `php://temp`

Comment: Relevant issue opened in the PHPExcel issue tracker:  https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/677

Comment: How can it be done? `PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('php://temp')` seems to be wrong... Do you have any idea? Will there be any problems with zip or so?

Comment: Sorry! Could you just provide an example? I may write something to php://temp (like [here](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#example-351)), but how should it be passed to `PHPExcel_IOFactory::load()`. With the file pointer?

Comment: From what I can tell, a solution involving `php://memory` (and similar) is not possible, because it's not possible to pass an already open stream to PHPExcel to load from it. Passing "php://memory" as filename to PHPExcel will make it open a separate fresh stream which will be empty.

Answer (score 21):

This might not be the most elegant solution but here is how I solved it:

```
public function fromString($data=null)
{
    $file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'excel_');
    $handle = fopen($file, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $data);
    $return = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);
    fclose($handle);
    unlink($file);
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer since php://memory and temp cannot be reused once closed. This solution is not ideal but its the only way that PHPexcel/phpspreadsheet accepts data from a string

Answer (score 2):

You must first create a reader for the excel file and then load that file from your constructed reader. Take a look at [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20140720042854/http://www.blrf.net/blog/38/code/php/reading-excel-files-with-phpexcel/) for full details.

Comment: The link is dead.