# PHPExcel_IOFactory::load() from php://memory

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to load an excel file from 'php://memory' stream.

Here's my code:

```
$path = 'http://<server>/test.xls';

$temp_file = fopen('php://memory', 'w+');

$file_contents = file_get_contents($path);
fwrite($temp_file, $file_contents);

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($temp_file);
fclose($temp_file);
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
PHP Warning:  pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in /var/resources/classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php on line 224
PHP Warning:  file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given in /var/resources/classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php on line 81
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open Resource id #15 for reading! File does not exist.' in /var/resources/classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php:82
Stack trace:
#0 /var/resources/classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php(280): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007->canRead(Resource id #15)
#1 /var/resources/classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php(191): PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile(Resource id #15)
#2 /var/www/syncDB.php(113): PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(Resource id #15)
#3 {main}
  thrown in /var/resources/classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php on line 82
```

I don't want to write the .xls file to disk. I tried to use tmpfile(), but I still get the same problem.
Is there something wrong with my code? Or do I inevitably need to pass the path of a file on disk for 'PHPExcel_IOFactory::load' to work with?

It maybe worth mentioning here that 'Mark Baker's' answer on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538626/load-excel-file-into-php-excel-from-variable?rq=1) suggests that using php://memory should be possible.

Comment: The error is self explanatory. `pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given` This is, because `PHPExcel_IOFactory::load` waiting for a path I think, and you pass a resource to it.

Comment: Could you please explain how I could get the path of '$temp_file = fopen('php://memory', 'w+')'?

Comment: I think, there is no way to do this. Or, you can create your own class, what is extends this `PHPExcel_IOFactory`, so called it `PHPExcel_IOFactoryFromMemory` and overwrite the `load` method.